# Material-ui : Pass object detail on KeyboardDatePicker onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I want to use `KeyboardDatePicker` for selecting the date for each row object in an array.

```
const meetings = [
  {id: 1, title: 'a', date: '14/5/2020'},
  {id: 2, title: 'b', date: '15/5/2020'}
];
  
const renderMeeting = () => 
  meetings.map(row => (
    <>
      <h2>{row.title}</h2>
      <KeyboardDatePicker 
        margin="normal" 
        label="Meeting Date" 
        value={row.date} 
        format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
        onChange={this.handleMeetingDateChange}
      />
    </>
  ))
```

How do I pass the `row` object along with the selected `date` to `handleMeetingDateChange()`?

P.S. I tried `react-datepicker` but the design is not consistent with other components on the page, that is the reason why I'm trying to make `KeyboardDatePicker` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function.

**Like This**

```js
...
let meetings = [{id: 1, title: 'a', date: '14/5/2020'}, {id: 2, title: 'b', date: '15/5/2020}];
const handleMeetingDateChange = (e, row) => {
  console.log(row);
  // rest code goes here
}
...
renderMeeting = () => {
  {meetings.map(row => (
    <h2>{row.title}</h2>
    <KeyboardDatePicker margin="normal" label="Meeting Date" value={r.meetingDate} format="dd/MM/yyyy" 
      onChange={(e) => this.handleMeetingDateChange(e, row)} 
  ))}
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the row data along with the event like this:

```js
 onChange={(event) => this.handleMeetingDateChange(event, row)}
```

Then, you can access those variables like this in your `handleMeetingDateChange`

```js
handleMeetingDateChange = (event, row) => {
   console.log(event, row);
   ...
}
```